# Check a div postion when -100% left

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to check a div position so when it comes to -100% left it returns to right 100%.

Im sutck in the part of checkin its position. Im using the console.log to check if it works, ive tried console.log(back1X.left) to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 setInterval(function() {

    var back1X = $('.back1').position();

 },100);

 $('.back1').animate({'left':'-100%'},50500);

 console.log(back1X);

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery *.animate()*'s [`complete` callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to call a function when the animation ends:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function loop() {
    $('.back1').css('left', '100%').animate({
      'left': '-100%'
    }, 2000, "linear", loop);
  })();
});
```

```css
.back1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="back1"></div>
```

Comment: Well i got it to work, by declarating the var first, but that your code is better! Is going to save me alot of time cuz i dont have to do the if () for every div. Tnks alot!

Comment: nice use of `animate()`